# Avoid duplicating the results on viewpage in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, foreach

I'm creating banking application in MVC 5.

Load table by bank and Load table rows by Bank,

[image]

But I cannot figure out do this exactly like above image,

This what I'm getting , it has 10 tables, instead just 2 tables

[image]

this is cshtml code for above view

```
    @model IEnumerable<albaraka.Models.ProductApprovals>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Product_Approvals";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>sadfasf</h2>
<h2>Product Approvals</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Student", FormMethod.Get))
    {


    <div> Filter by : Date @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)         Filter by : Country @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string) <input type="submit" value="Search" /> </div>


    }


@foreach (var item in Model)
{


    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SubsidaryName);   <p &nbsp />    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SubsidaryName);


    <table class="table">
        <tr>

            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProductNameEn)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProdcutNameAr)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CurrentStatus)
            </th>
            <th>
                Actions
            </th>
        </tr>



        @foreach (var inside in Model)
        {

            if (inside.Subsidary_ID == item.Subsidary_ID)
            {

         <tr>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => inside.ProductNameEn)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => inside.ProdcutNameAr)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => inside.CurrentStatus)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
            </td>
        </tr>
            }
        }
    </table>
}
```

This is Model class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace albaraka.Models
{
    public class ProductApprovals
    {

        public DateTime SearchDate { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string Product_ID { get; set; }
        public string Subsidary_ID { get; set; }
        public string SubsidaryName { get; set; }
        public string ProductNameEn { get; set; }
        public string ProdcutNameAr { get; set; }
        public string CurrentStatus { get; set; }

    }
}
```

This is Controller class

```
 public ActionResult Product_Approvals()
{
    var productApproveResult =(from p in db.AB_Product
                              join s in db.AB_Subsidary on p.Subsidary_ID equals s.SubsidaryID
                              select new ProductApprovals
                              {
                                  Product_ID    = p.ProductID,
                                  Subsidary_ID  = s.SubsidaryID,
                                  SubsidaryName = s.SubsidaryNameEn,
                                  ProductNameEn = p.ProductTitleEn,
                                  ProdcutNameAr = p.ProductTitleAr,
                                  CurrentStatus = p.Status                                         

                              }).ToList();

    return View(productApproveResult);
}
```

How to stop this repeating ,appricate if can show a way to this in view page

Comment: You have 2 `foreach` rendering all items in your model. Use a view model with properties for the bank and containing a collection of the data associated with that back. Then your looks are `foreach (var bank in Model) { // bank name etc foreach( var details in bank ) { // bank records } }`

Comment: I did exaclty like you said then `foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'albaraka.Models.ProductApprovals' because 'albaraka.Models.ProductApprovals' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'` getting this error , what should I do

Comment: You need to show your current models (so we can fix them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a view model(s) to represent what you want to display in the view. It should be something like

```
public class BankVM
{
  public string SubsidaryName { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<ProductVM> Products { get; set; }
}
public class ProductVM
{
  public string ProductNameEn { get; set; }
  public string ProdcutNameAr { get; set; }
  public string CurrentStatus { get; set; }
}
```

and pass a collection of `BankVM` to the view

```
@model IEnumerable<yourAssembly.BankVM>
@foreach(var bank in Model)
{
  <h3>@Html.DisplayFor(m => bank.SubsidaryName)</h3>
  <table>
    foreach(var product in bank.Products)
    {
      <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => product.ProductNameEn)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => product.ProductNameAr)</td>
        ....
      </tr>
    }
  </table>
}
```

In the controller, you can use a Linq `.GroupBy()` method to populate your collection of `BankVM`

Comment: do I need change model that using to pass data in controller method ?

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment, but you can keep your existing data model (although property `SearchDate` seems a bit odd), and use a `.GroupBy()` to group the records by `SubsidaryName`. The key will be the `SubsidaryName` and the values will be a list of products associated with that subsiduary. The just map the values to your collection of view models

Comment: do need use 'BankVM' model in controller class ?

Comment: Yes. Suggest you just start by creating a collection of 1 or 2 `BankVM` in the controller to test. Then you can look at creating the linq query to transform your data

Comment: when I put 'BankVM' on controller , its showing me that "BankVM does not contain definition for Product_ID, ProductNameEn , ..."

Comment: Of course it doesn't. Those are properties of `ProductsVM` (each bank contains a collection of products. I'm guessing your not really understanding this so I will create a DotNetFiddle for you shortly so you can see how it all works (give me 30-45 minutes)

Comment: I'm not well matured with theses technologies , could you please tell me how can I join with my database and Entity framework ,

Comment: Not sure what you mean. All I can do is answer the question as asked :) But it seems like you have tables for `AB_Subsidary ` and `AB_Product` so your join statement is unnecessary if you have the correct FK relationships and you data models are correct. You would need to ask a new question if you need help with that.